# Get attribute of <?xml-stylesheet ... ?> with PHP

Tags: php, xml, getelementsbytagname

I have this, in an XML file :

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="../StyleSheets/VDD11.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

I want to get the value of this attribute : `href=""`.
I'm working with PHP 5.
I've tried this code, but don't want to work :

```
function find_XSL_Fiche($file)
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load($file);
    echo $file.'<br />';
    $searchNode = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xml-stylesheet" );
    $xsl = "";
    foreach ($searchNode as $searchNode)
    {
        $xsl = $searchNode->getAttribute('href'); 
    }
    echo $xsl;
    return $xsl;
}
```

At the end, i want to get `../StyleSheets/VDD11.xsl`

Thanx

Comment: What errors do you get from this function?

Comment: `<?xml-stylesheet` isn't a tag. `?` isn't valid in tag names. the `<?...` "tag" is an xml declaration, which is a DOMDocumentType node: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php

Comment: So, how can I get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a processing instruction node. You can use Xpath to fetch it:

Fetch all processing instruction nodes:  
`//processing-instruction()`

Filtered by name:  
`//processing-instruction()[name() = "xml-stylesheet"]`

Cast the first found PI to a string: 
`string(//processing-instruction()[name() = "xml-stylesheet"])`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml(
 '<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet href="../StyleSheets/VDD11.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><xml/>'
);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'string(//processing-instruction()[name() = "xml-stylesheet"])'
  )
);
```

Output: https://eval.in/171053

```
string(47) "href="../StyleSheets/VDD11.xsl" type="text/xsl""
```

The content of a PI is text, it has no fixed structure. So you need to parse the data manually from the result using string functions or PCRE.

Comment: That's what I want ! I'll try and go back !

Comment: It's OK !!
Thanx you.